# Actualizar una tabla con datos de la misma tabla?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos sql con el gestor Oracle que va de la siguiente manera:

| Nombre | genero |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | M |
| Juan | M |
| Juan | M |
| Juan | M |
| Juan | F |
| Juan | NULL |
| Juan | NULL |
| Maria | F |
| Maria | F |
| Maria | F |
| Maria | M |
| Maria | NULL |
| ... | ... |

son cerca de 100000 registros y el requerimiento solicita que:

1- Generar una consulta en la que se pueda evidenciar la corrección de genero basado en los registros ya existentes, debería resultar una tabla con el nombre, el género anterior y el género corregido para cada registro, algo así:

| Nombre | genero | nuevo_genero |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | M | M |
| Juan | M | M |
| Juan | M | M |
| Juan | M | M |
| Juan | F | M |
| Juan | NULL | M |
| Juan | NULL | M |
| Maria | F | F |
| Maria | F | F |
| Maria | F | F |
| Maria | M | F |
| Maria | NULL | F |
| ... | ... | ... |

2- Actualizar la tabla para reemplazar los valores **NULL** por **F** o **M** según corresponda

Mi idea fue hacer un conteo inicial y actualizar según el máximo  valor que encuentre para cada nombre, pero tan solo es una idea, si pudieran ayudarme les agradezco

Primera idea:

La primera idea que me surgió fue hacer una busqueda de los nombres, el genero y agruparlos para que me muestre la cantidad de **F** y **M**que tiene cada nombre, y tal ves de ahí escoger el mayor para cada nombre, esta es la consulta:

```sql
SELECT 
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS.PRIMERNOMBRE,
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS.GENERO,
  COUNT(EJERCICIOS.DATOS.GENERO) AS "DatosGenero"
FROM
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS
GROUP BY
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS.PRIMERNOMBRE,
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS.GENERO
ORDER BY
  EJERCICIOS.DATOS.PRIMERNOMBRE,
  "DatosGenero" desc
```

y por ejemplo si juan tiene 3 registros **M** y 1 **F** que se escoja **M** como género nuevo

Comment: Te faltó agregar lo que has intentado, es decir el código sql.

Comment: Falta definir como identificas cual es el nuevo género.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes cuál es el género correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el género que mas veces aparece (el mas "popular") por cada nombre (exceptuando las filas con valor NULL en la columna género) hice una subquery parecida a la que hicistes vos (retornando la cantidad de veces que aparece cada género por cada nombre exceptuando los valores nulos) y luego utilizo window functions para obtener el genero mas popular de cada nombre (el género que mas veces se repite por cada nombre).

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre,
       FIRST_VALUE(genero) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre ORDER BY cantidad DESC) AS genero
FROM (
      SELECT nombre, genero, count(*) AS cantidad
      FROM EJERCICIOS.DATOS
      WHERE genero IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY nombre, genero
)
```

1. Query comparando el género de la fila con el género mas popular de cada nombre:

Ten en cuenta que si un nombre cada vez que aparece tiene un valor nulo en la columan género (no tiene género F y M), entonces el género corregido también será nulo.

```
SELECT t.nombre, t.genero, sq.genero AS genero_corregido
FROM EJERCICIOS.DATOS t
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT nombre,
                  FIRST_VALUE(genero) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre ORDER BY cantidad DESC) AS genero
           FROM (
                 SELECT nombre, genero, count(*) AS cantidad
                 FROM EJERCICIOS.DATOS
                 WHERE genero IS NOT NULL
                 GROUP BY nombre, genero)) sq ON t.nombre = sq.nombre
ORDER BY t.nombre, t.genero;
```

2. Actualizar el género con el género mas popular de cada nombre (podrías actualizar solo los género nulos si quisieras agregando la cláusula `WHERE genero IS NULL`):

```
UPDATE EJERCICIOS.DATOS t SET t.genero = (SELECT sq.genero
            FROM (
                  SELECT DISTINCT nombre,
                              FIRST_VALUE(genero) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre ORDER BY cantidad DESC) AS genero
                   FROM (
                    SELECT nombre, genero, count(*) AS cantidad
                    FROM EJERCICIOS.DATOS
                    WHERE genero IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY nombre, genero)) sq
                               WHERE t.nombre = sq.nombre)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT sq.genero
            FROM (
                  SELECT DISTINCT nombre,
                              FIRST_VALUE(genero) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre ORDER BY cantidad DESC) AS genero
                   FROM (
                    SELECT nombre, genero, count(*) AS cantidad
                    FROM EJERCICIOS.DATOS
                    WHERE genero IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY nombre, genero)) sq
                               WHERE t.nombre = sq.nombre);
```